# Identify the IP address

Tags: code-golf, string, number, internet

Identify whether an IP address is internal, global, link-local, or reserved.

Input should be an IPv4 address in decimal octets separated by periods.

Output should be `0` for link-local (RFC 3927), `1` for internal (RFC 1918), `2` for global IPs (Internet), and `3` for otherwise reserved addresses.

All these address types are described in [RFC 5735](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735):

> 3. Global and Other Specialized Address Blocks
>
> 0.0.0.0/8 - Addresses in this block refer to source hosts on "this"    network.  Address 0.0.0.0/32 may be used as a source address for this
> host on this network; other addresses within 0.0.0.0/8 may be used to
> refer to specified hosts on this network ([RFC1122], Section
> 3.2.1.3).
>
> 10.0.0.0/8 - This block is set aside for use in private networks.    Its intended use is documented in [RFC1918].  As described in that
> RFC, addresses within this block do not legitimately appear on the
> public Internet.  These addresses can be used without any
> coordination with IANA or an Internet registry.
>
> 127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host    loopback address.  A datagram sent by a higher-level protocol to an
> address anywhere within this block loops back inside the host.  This
> is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback.  As
> described in [RFC1122], Section 3.2.1.3, addresses within the entire
> 127.0.0.0/8 block do not legitimately appear on any network anywhere.
>
> 169.254.0.0/16 - This is the "link local" block.  As described in    [RFC3927], it is allocated for communication between hosts on a
> single link.  Hosts obtain these addresses by auto-configuration,
> such as when a DHCP server cannot be found.
>
> 172.16.0.0/12 - This block is set aside for use in private networks.    Its intended use is documented in [RFC1918].  As
> described in that    RFC, addresses within this block do not
> legitimately appear on the    public Internet.  These addresses can be
> used without any    coordination with IANA or an Internet registry.
>
> 192.0.0.0/24 - This block is reserved for IETF protocol assignments.    At the time of writing this document, there are no
> current    assignments.  Allocation policy for future assignments is
> given in    [RFC5736].
>
> 192.0.2.0/24 - This block is assigned as "TEST-NET-1" for use in    documentation and example code.  It is often used in conjunction with
> domain names example.com or example.net in vendor and protocol
> documentation.  As described in [RFC5737], addresses within this
> block do not legitimately appear on the public Internet and can be
> used without any coordination with IANA or an Internet registry.  See
> [RFC1166].
>
> 192.88.99.0/24 - This block is allocated for use as 6to4 relay    anycast addresses, in [RFC3068].  In contrast with previously
> described blocks, packets destined to addresses from this block do
> appear in the public Internet.  [RFC3068], Section 7, describes
> operational practices to prevent the malicious use of this block in
> routing protocols.
>
> 192.168.0.0/16 - This block is set aside for use in private networks.    Its intended use is documented in [RFC1918].  As
> described in that    RFC, addresses within this block do not
> legitimately appear on the    public Internet.  These addresses can be
> used without any    coordination with IANA or an Internet registry.
>
> 198.18.0.0/15 - This block has been allocated for use in benchmark    tests of network interconnect devices.  [RFC2544] explains that this
> range was assigned to minimize the chance of conflict in case a
> testing device were to be accidentally connected to part of the
> Internet.  Packets with source addresses from this range are not
> meant to be forwarded across the Internet.
>
> 198.51.100.0/24 - This block is assigned as "TEST-NET-2" for use in    documentation and example code.  It is often used in conjunction with
> domain names example.com or example.net in vendor and protocol
> documentation.  As described in [RFC5737], addresses within this
> block do not legitimately appear on the public Internet and can be
> used without any coordination with IANA or an Internet registry.
>
> 203.0.113.0/24 - This block is assigned as "TEST-NET-3" for use in    documentation and example code.  It is often used in conjunction with
> domain names example.com or example.net in vendor and protocol
> documentation.  As described in [RFC5737], addresses within this
> block do not legitimately appear on the public Internet and can be
> used without any coordination with IANA or an Internet registry.
>
> 224.0.0.0/4 - This block, formerly known as the Class D address    space, is allocated for use in IPv4 multicast address assignments.
> The IANA guidelines for assignments from this space are described in
> [RFC3171].
>
> 240.0.0.0/4 - This block, formerly known as the Class E address    space, is reserved for future use; see [RFC1112], Section 4.
>
> The one exception to this is the "limited broadcast" destination
> address 255.255.255.255.  As described in [RFC0919] and [RFC0922],
> packets with this destination address are not forwarded at the IP
> layer.
>
> 4.  Summary Table
>
> ```
> Address Block       Present Use                Reference
> 0.0.0.0/8           "This" Network             RFC 1122, Section 3.2.1.3
> 10.0.0.0/8          Private-Use Networks       RFC 1918
> 127.0.0.0/8         Loopback                   RFC 1122, Section 3.2.1.3
> 169.254.0.0/16      Link Local                 RFC 3927
> 172.16.0.0/12       Private-Use Networks       RFC 1918
> 192.0.0.0/24        IETF Protocol Assignments  RFC 5736
> 192.0.2.0/24        TEST-NET-1                 RFC 5737
> 192.88.99.0/24      6to4 Relay Anycast         RFC 3068
> 192.168.0.0/16      Private-Use Networks       RFC 1918
> 198.18.0.0/15       Network Interconnect
>                     Device Benchmark Testing   RFC 2544
> 198.51.100.0/24     TEST-NET-2                 RFC 5737
> 203.0.113.0/24      TEST-NET-3                 RFC 5737
> 224.0.0.0/4         Multicast                  RFC 3171
> 240.0.0.0/4         Reserved for Future Use    RFC 1112, Section 4
> 255.255.255.255/32  Limited Broadcast          RFC 919, Section 7
>                                                RFC 922, Section 7
> ```

### Rules

- Standard loopholes apply.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer wins.

Comment: For those of us who do not know this stuff, how do the single values here identify "blocks" and what values are "in" said blocks? Also which blocks are (2) and which are (3) (or are all non RFC3927/1918 (3) and everything else (2))?

Comment: @JonathanAllan The number after the slash in the IP address is the bitmask. http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/the-slash-after-an-ip-address-cidr-notation

Comment: That does not help me - I did not even think we would have that part in the input - "decimal octets separated by periods".

Comment: @JonathanAllan That's not for the input - it is the explanation of the blocks.

Comment: So the effective test for each block is to check if the bitwise-and of the slash-identified number of leading 1s matches the dot-delimited-identified value?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I guess...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48374/discussion-between-jonathan-allan-and-wat).

Comment: Could you please reformat the summary table so that it exactly shows what should return 0, what should return 1, etc.

Comment: @orlp The summary table is actually directly taken from the linked document.

Comment: This question should have some example inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>261</s> 207 bytes

```
v=>["169.254","10.|172.1[6789].|172.2\\d.|172.3[01]|192.168","x","0.|127|192.0.[02].|192.88.99|198.1[89].|198.51.100|203.0.113|2[345]\\d|22[^0123]"].reduce((a,x,i)=>v.search(x.replace(/\./g,"\\."))==0?i:a,2)
```

Readable version

```
v=>[
    "169.254",
    "10.|172.1[6789].|172.2\\d.|172.3[01]|192.168",
    "x",
    "0.|127|192.0.[02].|192.88.99|198.1[89].|198.51.100|203.0.113|2[345]\\d|22[^0123]"]
    .reduce((a,x,i)=>v.search(x.replace(/\./g,"\\."))==0?i:a,2)
```

Create an array with matching patterns, loop through the patterns and compare to input.  Return 0,1,2,3 as appropriate.

Edit: Fix bugs and streamline

Comment: I think you can save 18 bytes using `(a,x,i)=>x.every(t=>v.search("^"+t.replace(".","\.")))?a:i`.

Comment: V('172.16.0.1') => 2 (INVALID),V('172.17.1.1')=> 2 (INVALID), basically the whole "172.16" block does not work correctly. Have you tested this ? 
There is a syntax error - "\d" not escaped properly, resulting in a literal "d" match, and the patterns for this block are simply not correct too.

Comment: 172.16.0.1 returns 1 if you use the short version.  I made an error when copying and pasting the "readable" version.  As for the patterns being wrong, I made a mistake when calculating that subnet.

Comment: The mask for 172.16.0.0 is 12 bits, which means that the address range is: 172.16.0.0-172.31.255.255 (i.e. 172.16.X, 172.17 (!) e.t.c.)).

Test: I("172.17.0.1") => 2 (should be 1 instead)

Comment: (you can compute the address ranges at https://www.iplocation.net/subnet-calculator, to avoid doing that by hand)

Comment: @Neil thanks for the hint about .search

Comment: looks good now (downvote revoked)

Answer (score 1):

## ES6 (Javascript), <del>204</del>, <del>200</del>, <del>182</del>, 178 bytes

*EDIT*: Rewritten hex padding code, removed extra parenthesis, -4 bytes

*EDIT*: RegExp cleanup, streamline the result extraction, shorten the hex conversion code

*EDIT*: Refactored result extraction to bring it down to 200 bytes

Note, this should be pretty easy to shorten even further, by compressing the *RegExp* (as I never really bothered to do this)

**Golfed**

```
a=>/(^(?:00|7f|c0(?:5863|0{3}[02])|c6(?:1[23]|3364)|cb0071|e|f))|(^a9fe)|(^0a|^ac1|^c0a8)|./.exec(a.replace(/\d+./g,o=>(o|256).toString(16).slice(1))).reverse().findIndex(a=>a)^1
```

**Explanation**

*IP addresses* are shorter to write and easier to match, when converted to hexadecimal form, as CIDR masks tend to end on the 4 bit boundaries (with an exception of 198.18.0.0/15).

E.g.

```
0A000000-0AFFFFFF //10.0.0.0/8 
AC100000-AC1FFFFF //172.16.0.0/12
C0A80000-C0A8FFFF //192.168.0.0/16
```

can be matched as

```
/^0a|^ac1|^c0a8/
```

**Test**

```
I=a=>/(^(?:00|7f|c0(?:5863|0{3}[02])|c6(?:1[23]|3364)|cb0071|e|f))|(^a9fe)|(^0a|^ac1|^c0a8)|./.exec(a.replace(/\d+./g,o=>(o|256).toString(16).slice(1))).reverse().findIndex(a=>a)^1;

T=(i,o)=>{
  block=I(i);
  console.log(i,(block==o)?"OK":"NOT OK");
}

T("0.0.0.0",3)
T("10.0.0.0",1)
T("11.0.0.0",2)
T("127.0.0.0",3)
T("169.254.0.0",0)
T("169.253.0.0",2)
T("172.16.0.0",1)
T("172.31.0.0",1)
T("172.32.0.0",2)
T("192.0.0.0",3)
T("192.0.2.0",3)
T("192.88.99.0",3)
T("192.168.0.0",1)
T("192.167.0.0",2)
T("198.18.0.0",3)
T("198.51.100.0",3)
T("203.0.113.0",3)
T("224.0.0.0",3)
T("239.255.255.255",3)
T("240.0.0.0",3)
T("255.255.255.255",3)
T("241.0.0.1",3)
T("151.101.192.71",2)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 356 bytes

```
@echo off
set s=%1
if not %s==%s:.=% %0 %s:.= %
if %1.%2==169.254 exit/b0
if %1==10 exit/b1
if %1.%2==172.16 if %3 lss 32 exit/b1
if %1.%2==192.168 exit/b1
if %1==0 exit/b3
if %1==127 exit/b3
if %1 geq 224 exit/b3
for %%a in (18 19)do if %1.%2==192.%a exit/b3
for %%a in (192.0.0 192.0.2 198.51.100 203.0.113)do if %1.%2.%3==%%a exit/b3
exit/b2
```

Takes input as a command-line parameter and returns the result by setting the errorlevel.

Comment: The "224.0.0.0/4 Multicast" range has a _4_ bit mask, which means that it covers the addresses from 224.0.0.0 – 239.255.255.255 (and you only match 224). The same for "240" block.

Comment: @zeppelin Ah, so in fact anything >= 224 counts?

Comment: Yep, correct, everything > 224 is either multicast, reserved or broadcast, all of which map to the same output value.